# Registry entry does not run application on startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set a program to be launched on windows startup by adding it's path under the key `HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` in the registry.
If I target something like firefox.exe, it works. But if I target my .exe, it do nothing although I can launch it by clicking on the .exe.

I add a log to see if it starts and failed but nothing was written so I suppose that it's never launched.

Of course, I tried to switch off any antivirus.

Is there something to setup in the csproj? It's a basic WinForm project but I maybe forgot something.

Comment: Do you have any error message on screen / event log?

Comment: Does your application require administrator privileges?

Comment: @StephenReindl : I openned the event viewer and didn't see anything

Comment: @AngeloGeels : Not at all.

Comment: It's hard to tell. Windows will run everything what is written there. And it does it (as you tried another application and it works). So the problem is somewhere within your application. More likely you made a mistake with path, check this.

Comment: @Sinatr : That's what I though but when I take the path that I set in the registry and copy/paste it to the explorer, it target my .exe

Comment: What is the EXACT PATH that is written? Does it contain spaces? Is your PC 64bit?

Comment: @EricLaw : The exact path is 'C:\Program Files\Test app\Test.exe'. It's not a 64bits PC. As you can see, it contains space but if I target 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' (which contain spaces also), it works

Comment: @SeyoS: You should have double-quotes around the entire value, like `"C:\Program files\Test App\Test.exe"`. While the Firefox case may happen to work without quotes, that's only because there doesn't happen to be a subfolder named "Mozilla" in that folder.

Comment: @EricLaw : Found out what it was !! It's because when a program is run by adding its path in the registry, it's `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is set to `C:\System32` !  As I was trying to write something in a file, nothing could work. I manually set `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to the correct path and everything worked fine. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

```
RegistryKey rkApp = 
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

rkApp.SetValue("MyAPP", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

Comment: Already tried ! It didn't work either.

Comment: Whats ur Windows version

Comment: Forget about C#, manually goto Windows Registry then goto (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) after that create (String Value) key give exe name and set the exe path, then see whether it works on windows start.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that and it didn't work either. I put the 'C#' tag just to indicate that the program I try to launch was made with 'C#'.